# What if I used Segoe UI for printing?

Tags: fonts, print-design, licensing, windows

As I understand it, they have a license that applies only to web versions, an interface, or another digital output. But what if I want to print a few books or instructions?

Answer (score 1):

If you violate a license agreement you are liable for *whatever* repercussions that may initiate. The other party could seek restitution or a judgement.

Your question is no different than *any* question about breeching a contract or violating terms of an agreement. Even going so far as to say it's not any different than a question about a criminal act ... a la "I understand it's illegal, but what if I just murder a few people?" Yes, that's extreme. But the answer is kind of the same. If you're caught, you are culpable and subject to action.

Will you be caught, who knows. If you are caught, will you have a viable defense, it doesn't sound like it since you clearly understand what the license permits.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is too broad. What exactly will happen when applying this particular font? The license does not seem to prohibit printing.

Comment: @228warrant what exactly happens if you steal just one candy from a shop? maybe nothing, maybe you get caught. Same principle, we can't know more exactly what will happen if you print _just one book_.

Comment: @228warrant Your question is too broad. What **exactly** happens is up to the owner of the product under which license you violate. No one else can answer for them. I mean, if you *really* are that interested, contact the foundry and ask them what they do when someone violates their licensing. -- What *exactly* happens if you walk on your neighbor's lawn when there's a sign telling you not to?? it's all up to the neighbor. They could yell at you, ignore you, sue you, call the police for trespassing, shoot you.... there's no way to know *exactly*.